# Multivariate meta-analysis with sparse multivariate array

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, meta-analysis, resampling

I am wishing to conduct a meta-analysis that has many end-point measures that are all supposed to reflect a single concept - let's call it poor mental health.  That would include things like depression, anxiety, ptsd, etc.  So, on the surface, that sounds like a multivariate meta-analysis.  However, because there are many end-point measures, no study will have them all, and many studies may only have one or two.  Thus the effect-size array (and variance/covariance matrices) will contain many missing values.  The online text for [Doing Meta-Analysis in R: A Hands-on Guide](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/) indicates that multivariate analysis is suited to situations in which the outcomes "are assessed in most studies".  That does not seem to be the case here.  Also, the language from the manual for the meta() function in the metaSEM package states, "Missing values (NA) in y and their related elements in v will be removed automatically."  I can't tell with certainty, but if that means casewise deletion, I think there would be no remaining data.

A second approach would be to use a correlated and hierarchical effects model.  However, as I understand it, that requires providing a value for the common correlation between effect sizes (both within studies and between studies).  That feels like a very "bold" assumption and I wish there was a way around making it.  It might be possible to estimate all the covariances for a variance-covariance matrix for the effect sizes, so making the assumption that everything is r=.5 or something like that seems dodgy.

The reason I say that the Var-Cov matrix MIGHT be estimable is because I'm not using any of the conventional measures of effect size.  The effect size I wish to measure is a slope value from a natural spline based on IPData for each study.  I can get the SE for the slope values (hence the variances), but I suspect there's no formula derived for covariance of slopes across natural splines on correlated variables.  The solution I'm pondering (based in part on a comment by @Wolfgang [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/167015/94652) that refers to resampling) is to estimate the covariances by determining the correlation between slope values upon repeated resampling and then multiplying that by the square root of the product of the variances.

So, bearing in mind that this is my first meta-analysis and I'm likely confused on many fronts and not even asking the right questions, my questions are:

1. Is the resampling approach to generating the covariance estimates reasonable?
2. Am I correct in assuming that a sparse effect size matrix makes the multivariate approach undesirable?
3. If the correlated and hierarchical effects model is more appropriate, is there a way to make use of the variance/covariance information and avoid making the common correlation assumption?
4. Is there some better way to approach this problem that I simply haven't found yet?